# Instance of a class and correct initialization

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

I've ported over this project - https://gist.github.com/cmezak/8393434 and have it working but I have a question about the differences in handling instances of a class and also initializing properly.

In GameScene.swift I have created a property with an instance to an SKSpriteNode like so:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var nodeToScroll: SKSpriteNode

    init(size: CGSize) {
        nodeToScroll = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
        super.init(size: size)
        nodeToScroll.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        nodeToScroll.position = CGPointMake(0, size.height - nodeToScroll.size.height)
        self.addChild(nodeToScroll)
    }
}
```

And in GameViewController.swift I have:

```
var skView = SKView()
var scene = GameScene(size: CGSize())
var scrollView = UIScrollView()

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        skView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768))
        self.view.addView(skView)

        scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: skView.frame)
        scrollView.hidden = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.contentSize = scene.calculateAccumulatedFrame().size

        skView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

Like I said, this is working but my attempts to follow Swift patterns such as

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
```

it breaks. So my question is, how am I supposed to be handling cases where I need an instance of a scene outside of viewDidLoad? I thought this would be a simple port but now I've been staring at it so long I don't even know what I'm doing. Suggestions?

Edit: 
I edited the viewController to this:

```
var skView: SKView!
var scene: GameScene!
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        self.view.addSubview(skView)
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: skView.frame)
        scrollView.hidden = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.contentSize = scene.calculateAccumulatedFrame().size


        skView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}
```

I don't get any warnings or errors but when I run it I get "fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(coder:)' for class 'SwiftScrollKit.GameScene'"

So then I added

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

to the GameScene class and now get 'Can't add self as subview' -- hooboy... I don't know why this is throwing me for such a loop but I just must not be grasping something here that is probably right under my nose.

Comment: How does it break? What's the compiler error you're getting?

Comment: Also, did you intend to make `skView`, `scene` and `scrollView` global variables?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're setting `skView`, `scene` and `scrollView` values on creation, then throwing those objects away in `viewDidLoad`. I'm guessing you're doing this to silence errors about uninitialized variables. A better way to do this would be to declare your views with `!`, which means implicitly unwrapped optional. You won't have to test for nil before using those objects, but they'll blow up if you try to use them before they are set. They should look like this: `var skView: SKView!` `var scene: GameScene!`  `var scrollview: UIScrollView!`

Comment: @kubi - Well break was the wrong word, I simply don't get any of the nodes in the view. And yes, I wanted those as global variables.

Comment: @kubi - I am just leaving my office so can't reply in depth on my phone but will shortly.

Comment: It's not even 5 yet Christian. Tsk tsk

Comment: @kubi haha, yeah, well 5:00 is overrated. Anyway, I just edited my question with more code. I declared the properties as optionals and did a few more things but am still running into a wall. It's appropriate to facepalm now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to be stuck until you get the scope of your instance variables corrected. In the gist you linked to, they're declared inside the `@implementation { ... }` block of your `ViewController`, but here they're declared outside the class completely, which means they're global in scope.

Inside `viewDidLoad`, you're redefining `scene` and `skView` in the scope of that method, hiding the global values while you do your configuration. These local variables then get deallocated at the end of `viewDidLoad`, so you've lost access to whatever you've set up there. (They may live on in the view hierarchy, but your global variables won't work.)

You'll want to move those global variables inside the class, and then access them using `self.variableName` so you don't mix them up with local variables. Other methods in the class will then also have access to what you've set up in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var skView: SKView!
    var scene: GameScene!
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scene = // load the scene
        self.skView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 768.0))
        self.view.addSubview(self.skView)
        // etc
    }
}
```

Finally, the "Can't add self as subview" error is happening because of this:

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
// ...
self.view.addSubview(skView)
```